# Unable to install angular-cli globally

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Hi When I'm trying to install angular-cli I'm getting this error. Please help me out of this.

```
C:\>npm -v
5.5.1

C:\>node -v
v8.9.3

C:\>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular-devkit/architect@0.12.3

npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@angular/cli'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\44128785\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-24T09_50_
04_779Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to install angular-cli, you need to have its dependencies which matches the version. Follow these steps

```
1) Rename your current node_modules to node_modules_backup
2) `npm install -g`
3) `npm install angular-cli -g`
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using an older version of npm which is not compatible with latest version of angular cli.

You can either, uninstall node/npm and install the latest version, or you can upgrade npm. Find the upgrade information [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Upgraded my npm from 5.5.1 to latest(6.7.0) but no luck :-(

Comment: I've updated my node to 8.12.0, npm to 6.7.0 and installed cli's older version 6.0.8. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also somehow triggered the NPM pain train today (`No matching version found for @angular-devkit/{subpackage}@0.12.3`).

Are you using a private registry?  If so, try downloading the packages for now without using it (and using the standard npm registry): that resolved my issue until our nexus repo can get itself worked out

Comment: Yes I'using private registry.. But I've updated my node to 8.12.0, npm to 6.7.0 and installed cli's older version 6.0.8. That solved my issue.